# NSUserDefaults with Facebook login

Tags: swift, facebook, nsuserdefaults

I am quite new to programming, so please bear with me. I have a signIn/signUp feature with Facebook SDK. When user signs up, I display user's first name, last name and profile picture on profilePageViewController. However, when user leaves the app and goes to this viewController all labels and imageView(here I actually show file from assets) are blank. I came with NSUserDefaults for such cases, but don't know how to implement it. You can find code for NSUserDefaults at the bottom that I came up with browsing in internet, but can't understand where to place it and how to call it, neither quite sure that my code is accurate for my case. Right now it is not being called even. Appreciate your help and suggestions

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit
 import Parse

 class ProfilePageViewController: UITableViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {


@IBAction func userBeenHereButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBOutlet weak var userWantToGoButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var profilePageTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureImageView: UIImageView!

let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = {
    let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
    button.readPermissions = ["email"]
    return button

}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.firstNameLabel.text = ""
    self.lastNameLabel.text = ""
    self.profilePictureImageView?.image

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.center = view.center
    loginButton.delegate = self


    if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
        fetchProfile()

    }
}

func fetchProfile() {
    print("func fetch profile was called")

    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        var firstNameData = ""
        var lastNameData = ""
        var emailData = ""
        var pictureData = ""


        if let firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name") as?  String {
            print(firstName)
            firstNameData = firstName

        }

        if let lastName = result.valueForKey("last_name") as? String {
            print(lastName)
            lastNameData = lastName
        }

        if let email = result.valueForKey("email") as? String {
            print(email)
            emailData = email
        }

        if let picture = result.valueForKey("picture")as? NSDictionary,
            data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary,
            url = data["url"] as? String {
            print(url)
            pictureData = url
        }


        let user = PFUser()
        let username = "\(firstNameData)_\(lastNameData)"


        user["firstName"] = firstNameData
        user["lastName"] = lastNameData
        user["email"] = emailData
        user["picture"] = pictureData
        user["username"] = username
        user["password"] = emailData




        let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username

        if  currentUser == nil {
            user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock() {(success, error) -> Void in
                if success {
                    print("successfully saved")
                } else {

                    do
                    {
                        try PFUser.logInWithUsername(username, password: emailData)
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    self.updateUI()
                    print("profile should not be blank")

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    print("complete login")
    fetchProfile()
    nsUserDefaults()


}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("successfully logged out")
    PFUser.logOut()

    self.firstNameLabel.text = ""
    self.lastNameLabel.text = ""
    self.profilePictureImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "user.png")


}

func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
    return true
}



func updateUI () {


    if let userFirstName = PFUser.currentUser()?["firstName"] as? String    {
        firstNameLabel.text = userFirstName
    } else {
        self.firstNameLabel.text = ""
    }

    if let userLastName = PFUser.currentUser()?["lastName"] as? String  {
        lastNameLabel.text = userLastName
    } else {
        self.lastNameLabel.text = ""
    }

    if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["picture"] as? String,
        url = NSURL(string: userPicture),
        data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
        image = UIImage(data: data)
    {
        profilePictureImageView?.image = image

    }
    else {
        self.profilePictureImageView.image = nil
    }
}
    func nsUserDefaults(){
            let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            defaults.setObject(self.firstNameLabel.text, forKey: "firstName")
            defaults.setObject(self.lastNameLabel.text, forKey: "lastName")
            if let imageData = defaults.objectForKey("picture") as? NSData {
                if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                    self.profilePictureImageView.image = image
                    defaults.removeObjectForKey("picture")
                    defaults.synchronize()
                    print("NSUser")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem with following approach. Declared static variables

```
static let firstNameNSUserDefaults = "FIRST_NAME"
static let lastNameNSUserDefaults = "LAST_NAME"
static let profilePictureNSUserDefaults = "PROFILE_PICTURE"
```

Edited updateUI and nsUserDefaults functions so they look like this now

```
func updateUI () {

    if let userFirstName = PFUser.currentUser()?["firstName"] as? String    {
        firstNameLabel.text = userFirstName
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        prefs.setObject(firstNameLabel.text, forKey: ProfilePageViewController.firstNameNSUserDefaults)
    } else {
        self.firstNameLabel.text = ""
    }

    if let userLastName = PFUser.currentUser()?["lastName"] as? String  {
        lastNameLabel.text = userLastName
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        prefs.setObject(lastNameLabel.text, forKey: ProfilePageViewController.lastNameNSUserDefaults)
    } else {
        self.lastNameLabel.text = ""
    }

    if let userPicture = PFUser.currentUser()?["picture"] as? String,
        url = NSURL(string: userPicture),
        data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url),
        image = UIImage(data: data)
    {
        profilePictureImageView?.image = image
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 100)
        prefs.setObject(imageData, forKey: ProfilePageViewController.profilePictureNSUserDefaults)

    }
    else {
        self.profilePictureImageView.image = nil
    }
}

func nsUserDefaults(){

    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let firstNameData = prefs.stringForKey(ProfilePageViewController.firstNameNSUserDefaults) {
        firstNameLabel.text = firstNameData
    }

    if let lastNameData = prefs.stringForKey(ProfilePageViewController.lastNameNSUserDefaults) {
        lastNameLabel.text = lastNameData
    }

    if let imageData = prefs.objectForKey(ProfilePageViewController.profilePictureNSUserDefaults) as? NSData {

        let storedImage = UIImage.init(data: imageData)
        profilePictureImageView.image = storedImage
    }

}
```

Finally called nsUserDefaults function in the end of viewDidLoad.